# Storing multiple attributes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I have a database (for a PHP web application) with a table `client` having various attributes.
Two such attributes are `phone_numbers` and `emails`.

One client can have zero or more phone-numbers and zero or more e-mails.

I'd like to store the client table as:

```
create table client (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  ...
  text phone_numbers,
  text e-mails) default character set utf8
```

The phone-numbers would have a format `"pn1:type1,pn2:type2,...,pnN:typeN"`
and e-mails would have a format `"e1,e2,...,eN"`.

Are there some important problems with this design I could encounter later?

Is there a better design for these issues and why?

Comment: is this actually mysql? if so its varchar() not text

Comment: base64encoded serialised arrays would typically be used in this situation. But IMO, the best solution is to have a separate table with multiple phones or emails.

Comment: AS you want to have multiple phone and email. This is not a normalized design. It is better to have two separate tables for phone and email. You can have two column one for foreign key as client_id and other will be the phone or email value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure you are thinking of is not normalized and will give you problems... when you search, when you display data, and in many other situations.

It is better to have either 3 tables:

```
client      (id, ...)
phonenumber (id, client_id, phone_type, phone_number)
email       (id, client_id, email)
```

... or just 2 tables:

```
client  (id, ...)
contact (id, client_id, contact_type, contact_text)
```

I prefer the latter, as it provides more flexibility (it can handle social network accounts, webpages and many other ways to contact people). It is easier to search on than the 3 table structure, and it does not require to be altered when you want to manage a new contact type.

Comment: so what happens when you have more than one phone and only one email? the second design is flawed.

Comment: Why do you say that? You just have more than one row with the same client_id and contact_type. PRIMARY KEY is (id). UNIQUE key is (client_id, contact_type, contact_text).

Comment: @Frazz Thank you for answer. I let it open for a while yet, if somebody would like to tell something important to this design issue yet.

Comment: @xralf go with option 1. Following normalization you should have a table for phone numbers and a table for email.. There can be unforseen obstacles when using the second option. Both are there in the answer so you should accept the answer still :)